# Cakephp multiselect selected issue

Tags: cakephp

My array is this:

```
Array
(
    [9] => Yashobanta
    [80] => Yash
    [83] => Ramesh
)
```

and the selected array is this:

```
Array
(
    [9] => Yashobanta
    [83] => Ramesh
)
```

and my ctp input is this:

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->input('Dispensary.role', array(
        'options' => $dispensary_users,
        'class' =>'form-control dispensary_users_dd',
        'label'=>false,
        'style'=>'width:300px;',
        'multiple'=>true,
        'id' => 'editDispensaryRole')
    );
?>
```

I am getting this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try this

```
$options  = array( 
    '9' => 'Yashobanta'
    '80' => 'Yash'
    '83' => 'Ramesh'
);

$selected = array( 
    '9' => 'Yashobanta'
    '83' => 'Ramesh'
);

echo $this->Form->input('Dispensary.role', 
    array(
        'multiple' => true, 
        'options' => $options, 
        'selected' => $selected
    )
);
```